# How to button inactive after tweening alpha to 0?

Tags: flash, button, opacity, tween

I'm using 4 pictures, two of which are hidden behind the other two.
If you click the first two, they should disappear, and then you get to click the two hidden underneath.
However, after tweening they're still active, and if I remove the mouse listener, they're also in the way. If I use pic.visible = false, it disappears without a tween.
How can I fix this?

My code:

```
//pic4 and pic5 are on top layer
//pic2 and pic3 are on bottom layer

import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;


pic2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseHandler1);
pic3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseHandler2);
pic4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseHandler3);
pic5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseHandler4);


function mouseHandler3(event:MouseEvent):void{
var t3:Tween = new Tween(pic4, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
}

function mouseHandler4(event:MouseEvent):void{
var t4:Tween = new Tween(pic5, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
}

function mouseHandler1(event:MouseEvent):void{
var t1:Tween = new Tween(pic2, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
}

function mouseHandler2(event:MouseEvent):void{
var t2:Tween = new Tween(pic3, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

import tweening event :

```
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
```

Then you can do :

```
function mouseHandler3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var t3:Tween = new Tween(pic4, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
    t3.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onTweenEnd );
}

function onTweenEnd (e:TweenEvent) : void 
{
    pic4.visible = false;
    //Do whatever else
}
```

This beginner **[guide](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3tweenclass/)** might help you. Also if any error issues arise then declare `var t3:Tween;` outside of any functions (especially **not** inside a mouse event) then to make a new tween inside a function you simply use :  `t3 = new Tween(pic4, etc ...)`